# "Двойной порт" на выделенном сервере

Tags: url, хостинг, порты, хост

Пишу программу на Python, где использую Flask, который присваивает для доступа порт `5000`.

Каким образом будет выглядеть url-адрес, если сайт, предоставляющий выделенный хостинг, присваивает всему моему рабочему пространству порт `35067`

Comment: Подробней, что значит *присваивает всему моему рабочему пространству порт 35067*

Comment: Вероятно, никак. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Comment: Всё, что сделано мной на хосте доступно только через порт 35067